# Display DateTime iin C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DateTime variable  selected in a 1st window and I'm trying to display in in a 2nd window. It connects to the DB as it should be,but it appears a random data from the DB,not the selected one.
Here is the code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?");
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        win1.Show();


    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string connectionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connectionString =
                @"Data Source=IBWS05\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=Interview;Integrated Security=True";

            try
            {

                SqlConnection con =
                    new SqlConnection(
                        @"Data Source=IBWS05\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=Interview;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "insert into [Event] (Description,StartData,EndData,Type) values (@description,@startdata,@endata,@type)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", descriptionTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("startData", StartDate.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("endata", EndDate.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("type", typeTxt.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }


        ////Window2 win = new Window2(id);
        //Window2 win3 = new Window2();
        //this.Close();
        //win3.Show();

        SqlConnection conn =
                    new SqlConnection(
                        @"Data Source=IBWS05\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=Interview;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        int query= Convert.ToInt32(comm.CommandText = "select MAX(StartData) from [Events]");



        Window2 win = new Window2(query);
        win.Show(); 
    }
```

The error is input string was not in a correct format. How can I convert it?

Comment: Your code won't _even_ compile since `Convert.ToDateTime` returns `DateTime` not `int`. There is no point to send your `CommandText` to `ToDateTime` method. You need to _execute_ your query first and cast it (I assume it is a `datetime` or `datetime2` typed) `DateTime` explicitly. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on your problem.

Comment: Also don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size. Use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically as well.

Comment: If it is written Convert.ToInt32 int compiles but,shows me a random.

Comment: What `select MAX(StartData) from [Events]` query returns exactly? What is the type of `StartData` column?

Comment: The StartData column is DateTime and MAX(StartData) is the last data inserted in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to look at/consider in your code, first is your issue.
This line of code:

```
int query= Convert.ToDateTime(comm.CommandText = "select MAX(DateTime) from [Events]");
```

Won't achieve what you are after as you aren't executing the code. You are actually trying to convert your command object to a Date Time.

Earlier in your method you are writing to the database and part of that you call the following:

> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

There are various other methods that you have on the command object that all work in different ways. To read about them visit this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx), but essentially you probably want to use the ExectuteScalar method for what you are trying to do.

Next, I would consider moving your connection string to the app.config file and accessing it from there rather than typing it out multiple times.

And finally, I would use a using statement for each of your Connection's so that you ensure they are being disposed of correctly.

Just some extra food for thought.